# Name of connector that connects wires to washer drain pump

Tags: washing-machine

I'm looking to replace a connector that connects to my washers' drain pump.
I first suspected the drain pump to have gone bad, but it looks like the wire itself was burnt or sheared off. I was going to splice the wire back together but figured it would be better to replace the connector all together.

I've attached some pictures to help identify it.

The washer is an Amana NTW4516FW1

[image]

Comment: You might get better answers over at electronics.stackexchange.com -- connector identification questions are quite common there, and if it's not proprietary, someone there may know what it's called.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica Thanks! I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's a good chance the connector could be proprietary or custom. Also, the connector housing and the two terminals inside are separate parts. Amana likely won't offer these in their parts catalog.

Amana might have bought that component from a connector manufacturer. The major players (Molex, Tyco, Hirose, etc) usually have their name or symbol somewhere on the parts they make, but if you can't find a recognizable mark, it's not likely to be a catalog item available through an electronic components distributor.

The connector looks fine; I don't see any signs of damage (discoloration, deformation, etc). I'd solder and heat-shrink the wire and resolve whatever damaged it in the first place.

Comment: Totally agree with the solder and heat-shrink (or just strip and connect with a wire nut...)

Answer (score 2):

the terminals look like standard quick-disconnet connectors.

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=quick_disconnect

Sometimes called by the trade-name "Fast-on"

https://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/quick-disconnects/Y30dJ.html

compatible contact parts are common as dirt

The gray housing is probably specific to that appliance  manufacturer, but it may be possible to remove the contacts and re-use the housing (but that will need the right style of contacts) , or to substitute individual connectors for that dual connector.